# How to Assign a project to specific user only in SonarQube?

Tags: permissions, sonarqube

I want that when a project is scanned and it's scan result is created only Admin and a specific user can see that project in dashboard and all other places and only he can access that project. Also I want to send email to that user when project was scanned.

I know I can assign role to user and set permissions for it by going to that project, but should I have follow all these steps for this? Can't I just select a user from UI so that only that selected user can view that project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define project permissions for the scanned project with only that user and admin having the permission to "Browse" the project.
If you need to do that repeatedly you may use permission templates.
See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-ProjectPermissions.

Comment: Thanks for this quick help. I need another help too. Is it possible to email report to user to whom project is assigned? By Assigned I mean allowed permissions. Basically what I want is to send report emails to the user who's project was analyzed.

Comment: It's not possible for the moment to send project reports, but with the Governance plugin (http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/), reports of views can be sent to anyone.

Comment: Whereever I install this plugin, sonar scanner stop working and gives error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to Assgin one project to a whole group of users in SonarQube 6.7.3 so the steps where the following:

Administration->Projects->Managment->Actions(of the desired project)->edit Permissions

[image: steps]

And then, I don't know why but the current users and groups registered are not shown instantly so what you need to do is to use the search tool and search for the group or user that you are looking for. They will appear below so you'll be able to tick the permissions that you want. Also you should select the private radio button so nobody but the users or groups you selected can access the project.

[image: 2ndSteps]